# Privacy of App ID, Bundle ID - What is the Importance?

Tags: ios

I'm self taught, and program alone so I have no one else to ask what might be a dumb question but at the same time could be very important. Is keeping your iOS appID and Bundle ID private important? Everyone always whites out their IDs on SO.  Or do these pieces of information make their way around the web in plain text?

I ask because I stumbled on a text document of applinks that shows the corresponding iOS app associated with the link and its appID: "ABDJCEI890.com.john.smith" along with associated keys for a popular API. Mine was on the list and I was taken aback thinking that that information should be private.

There are hundreds of apps on this list, just a quick scroll reveals the IDs and keys of: lonelyPlanet, NBCUniversal, Vevo, etc.

Is this important or not important?

Comment: Ever use iTunes to backup your iOS device? Go to `~/Music/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications` on your Mac. There you will find every ipa of every app you own. Unzip one and look at the Info.plist in Xcode. You now know the bundle id of the app. It's no secret.

Answer (score 0):

Important, no. Embarrassing, perhaps. For example, `com.DanielStorm.iHaveNoIdeaWhatImDoing` as a published application's Bundle Identifier might be a little awkward if you're trying to maintain a professional image on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I always hid my app id & bundle id for two reasons

- app id, So the competitors wouldn't know what's my app name and what I am working on
- bundle id, for most users it their real apple developer name. I don't like the world to know that either

Their maybe other better valid reasons that I don't know.

As for the site that you just mentioned, they didn't get appID info directly from some apple website and I bet they used some sort of web crawlers program that downloaded and decompiled their ipa and read info.plist file. It's really easy to do that. I bet you wouldn't find info for apps that are paid and were never made free.

To be honest its a shame apple doesn't encrypt everything in a ipa. Only certain data is encrypted the rest is easily viewable with a text editor